# Can you check if an F key (F1, F2, etc) is being pressed with a standard C++ function?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I'm trying to develop for both Windows and Linux (Ubuntu/Debian specifically) in C++, and I need to detect when an F key is pressed by another application. I want to change as little code as possible to migrate it across OS's, so can I check if an F key (F1, for example) is pressed with a std function? Can I use std::cin for this, or one of its functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such API in the std library.